# Optimization: Find the minimum cost from renting plans

Tags: sorting, optimization, multidimensional-array, combinations, dynamic-programming

Given a company will be renting cores for k tasks a day for n days, and a 2D array plans for pricing of cores is given, each sub-array in plans has 4 elements in order representing:

1. the start day of this plan
2. the end day of this plan
3. how many tasks can this plan take each day
4. the cost for each task each day

The goal is to write a python code to calculate the minimum cost needed.

For example, an input of n = 5, k = 7, plans =[[1, 3, 5, 2], [1, 4, 5, 3], [2, 5, 10, 1]] will return 44, since:

Day1: will choose plan 1 for 5 tasks for 2x5 costs and plan 2 for the rest 2 tasks for 3x2, a total of 16.

Day2 to Day5: will all choose plan 3 for 7 tasks for 1 cost each task each day, a total of 7x1x4 = 28.

The final return would be 16 + 28 = 44.

Some other test cases are:

n = 4, k = 4, plans = [[1, 4, 4, 5], [1, 4, 2, 5], [1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 3, 2]] # 49

n = 4, k = 4, plans = [[1, 1, 4, 5]] # 20, If there are only x consective available days (where x < n), then return the minimum cost for day x.

My current approach is the following:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import math

def min_cost(n, k, plans):
    # Sort the plans by start day and then by cost per task
    plans.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[3]))

    # Create a dictionary to map each day to its list of suitable plans
    plans_for_day = {day: [] for day in range(1, n + 1)}
    for plan in plans:
        start_day, end_day, _, _ = plan
        for day in range(start_day, end_day + 1):
            if day <= n:  # Only consider days within the range
                plans_for_day[day].append(plan)

    # Initialize the dp array with infinity values for each day
    dp = [float('inf')] * (n + 1)
    dp[0] = 0  # No cost for 0 days

    # Iterate through each day
    for day in range(1, n + 1):
        # Consider plans that are valid for this day using the dictionary
        valid_plans = plans_for_day[day]

        for r in range(1, len(valid_plans) + 1):
            for plan_subset in combinations(valid_plans, r):
                total_cost = 0
                remaining_tasks = k
                total_capacity = sum(p[2] for p in plan_subset)

                # Check if the total capacity of the subset is at least k
                if total_capacity < k:
                    continue

                for plan in sorted(plan_subset, key=lambda x: x[3]):
                    _, _, capacity, cost_per_task = plan
                    tasks_covered = min(remaining_tasks, capacity)
                    total_cost += tasks_covered * cost_per_task
                    remaining_tasks -= tasks_covered

                # Update the dp array for the current day
                if remaining_tasks == 0:
                    dp[day] = min(dp[day], dp[day - 1] + total_cost)
                    break  # Early stopping when a valid combination is found

    # Return the least cost on the last day or the previous day with a finite cost
    return dp[n] if dp[n] != float('inf') else next((dp[day] for day in range(n, 0, -1) if math.isfinite(dp[day])), -1)
```

The constrains for this question are the following:

1. 1 <= n, m <= 10^4, n being number of days, m being number of plans.
2. 1 <= k <= 500, k being the number of tasks each day.
3. 1 <= plan[0], plan[1] <= n.
4. 1 <= plan[2] <= k.
5. 1 <= plan[3] <= 10^9

I created this test function to mass test:

```py
import random
import time

def generate_test_case(n_max, m_max, k_max):
    n = random.randint(1, n_max)  # Number of days
    m = random.randint(1, m_max)  # Number of plans
    k = random.randint(1, k_max)  # Tasks per day

    plans = []
    for _ in range(m):
        start = random.randint(1, n)
        end = random.randint(start, n)  # Ensure end is not before start
        capacity = random.randint(1, k)
        cost = random.randint(1, 10**9)
        plans.append([start, end, capacity, cost])

    return n, k, plans

# Your min_cost function here

# Generate a large test case
n_max = 10**4
m_max = 10**4
k_max = 500

n, k, plans = generate_test_case(n_max, m_max, k_max)

# Measure execution time
start_time = time.time()
result = min_cost(n, k, plans)
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Test case: n={n}, m={len(plans)}, k={k}")
print(f"Result: {result}")
print(f"Execution Time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

My approach takes at least 20mins (and still going) to run at this level of magnitude, is there a way to optimize it?